# Data table is not accepting the changes made in the grid view for updating the database

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datatable, windows

I have the below code where I'm trying to update a database from the c# grid view change made in Windows application....

The code is not updating the SQL Server database... I'm not sure where exactly the issue occurs. Everything seems to be fine...

Or is there a way to update the database table usig the "update query statement" again the point is how to write the udate statement for any value changes in the data grid view ?

I presume there might be an issue with binding and the select command statements...

Could anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue ?

```
public partial class KnowledgeBaseForm : Form
{
    private SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
    private DataTable DT = new DataTable();

    private void button_retrievekb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * From Table1", con);

            SDA.Fill(DT);

            bindingsource.DataSource = DT;
            dataGridView.DataSource = bindingsource;

            if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                dataGridView.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Knowledge Base Rules Found");
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Update these values?", "Confirm Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //binding the datasource with the changes made in the gridview
            bindingsource.DataSource = dataGridView.DataSource;

            scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(SDA);                 
            SDA.Update((DataTable) bindingsource.DataSource);

            MessageBox.Show("Updates successfully submitted to CoSD");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you have more errors, but first of all remove "DT.AcceptChanges();", that will accept all changes, so these become to "Unchanged" then SDA.Update will do nothing as it does not "see" any change.

Comment: @Gusman2 : Thanks for the comments... I didnt hav eany error's shown... but the database is not getting upated... please see the edited code now...  I'm making the changes during run time in the datagrid view and learnt some links to use this method.... now i removed it but still its not getting updated....

Comment: In your click event, try only this code: if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Update these values?", "Confirm Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource);}